# Show block of html code if on a certain page

Tags: javascript, html

I need to grab the current page name the person is on, if that page name matches any pages in an array then I need to show a block of html that shows a search box. How can I do that in JavaScript? So far I have this to find the current page:

```
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: why include some piece of HTML the server shoud know will never be displayed? This should be solved server-side, isn't it so?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Dont understand what your asking. I need to show a search box based on the current page a person is on. Its on a third party server so I cant use php or any other server side scripting to do this otherwise I would get the current url via php and say if current page needs to display this block of html then display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aPages = [ 'page1', 'page2', 'page3' ];

if (aPages.indexOf) {
    if (aPages.indexOf(sPage) >= 0) {
        // We found a match.
    } else {
        // The page is not in the array.
    }
} else {
    // We're using an old browser that doesn't provide support for Array.indexOf.
}
```